# how to use pywhois module in gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pywhois

I have problems when try to import [pywhois module](http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/), i can import my own module but still have troubles when import pywhois. I moved the pywhois folder in my project folder **domain**, the screentshot is below:
[image]

This is the import and calling statment below:
import part:

```
from pywhois import *
```

calling part:

```
 w = whois('hackbo.com')
 self.response.out.write(w)
```

The problems is it will always throw a http 500 error, error text is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/li/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 700, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/home/li/Desktop/google_appengine/domain/main.py", line 43, in get
    w = whois('hackbo.com')
  File "pywhois/__init__.py", line 12, in whois
    text = nic_client.whois_lookup(None, domain, 0)
  File "pywhois/whois.py", line 157, in whois_lookup
    result = self.whois(query_arg, nichost, flags)
  File "pywhois/whois.py", line 100, in whois
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

What is this error means? why i could import my own module but can not import pywhois?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to use whois in google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266588/how-to-use-whois-in-google-app-engine). Please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google App Engine doesn't support the `socket` module, which `pywhois` uses. It allows you to `import socket`, but [it's an empty module](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python).

Answer (score -1):

```
import whois
site = input ("Enter Site : ")
n = whois.whois (site)
print (n)
```

this is best whois
Enjoy that, easy.

Comment: Format your answer and add somer description

Comment: install Cmder 
type : cd  desktop or (find your whois file)
and type your file name for example  (cd desktop , cd python ,  whois.py)
and enter your site :