# How to use whois in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, whois

I know there is [pywhois](http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/) but it can't used in gae, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254577/how-to-use-pywhois-module-in-gae). But i really need this function to verify whether a domain is registered, is there other way to implement whois by pure python? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find a HTTP Api to get whois like http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/ and with [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) you can fetch informations.

An another solution is to create this webservice with a micro instance from [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) and install the module pywhois, you need to just create the interface in HTTP.